# Trying to understand "Dynamic Evaluation Vulnerabilities in PHP applications"

Tags: php

Example from here
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection#Preventing_code_injection

Dynamic evaluation vulnerabilities - dynamic variable evaluation

> As defined in "Dynamic Evaluation Vulnerabilities in PHP applications": PHP supports "variable variables," which are variables or expressions that evaluate to the names of other variables. They can be used to dynamically change which variable is accessed or set during execution of the program. This powerful and convenient feature is also dangerous.
>
> If the attacker provides "safevar=bad" in the query string, then $safevar will be set to the value "bad".

Tried to do as in example

```
<?php
$safevar = "0";
$param1 = "";
$param2 = "";
$param3 = "";
# my own "register globals" for param[1,2,3]
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
echo  $key = $value. '<br>';
//echo  $key = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'). '<br>';
}

echo $safevar;
if ($safevar == 'bad') {
echo 'may harm<br>';
}
?>


<form action="<?php echo (htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"])) ?>" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="username2" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_GET['username2']); ?>">
<input name="update2" type="submit" id="update2" value="Update2">
</form>
```

But I can not get `$safevar == 'bad'`

Please advice why. Trying to understand to know how to protect my own code

Comment: Insert this as the first line of your `foreach`: `$$key = $value;`. Then if you use a query string of `?safevar=bad` you'll see that any variable - even ones not intended as writable - can be modified.

Comment: Why are you trying to protect yourself from a setting that no one in their right mind has enabled in years, was deprecated in 5.3, and was completely removed in 5.4? Everyone with a brain knows that, in hindsight, `register_globals` was the dumbest thing anyone's ever implemented. The ***real*** moral of the story is to always *strictly* validate *all* user input.

Comment: @Sammitch: please ease up on the "everyone with a brain" stuff. Beginners have to start somewhere, and this topic isn't obvious to everyone.

Comment: @Sammitch. I am learning. Want to understand on what conditions some code may harm and how to avoid possible problems.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you should be learning how to properly validate inputs rather than trying to replicate an old security issue by intentionally writing code you know is terrible. Learning to protect against exploits that depend on `register_globals` is like rehashing 'duck and cover' as protection against a soviet nuclear attack. Your time will be *much better spent* learning proper input validation techniques which will help you protect yourself against attacks that are actually happening today.

Comment: And with regard to 'variable variable' exploits, the simple answer is: don't use them. Esoteric security concerns aside, there is almost nothing you can do with variable variables that you can't do in a much simpler, clearer way using a different construct like an associative array. VVs are almost always an indicator of a problem being approached incorrectly.